# In reactjs is it ok to execute async functions in componentDidMount and do a setstate in the resulting callback?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My understanding is that the right place to do my initial ajax data loading is in componentDidMount.

It seems to me that what I want to do is "setState" of the result of the several async functions that I will execute.

Thus I need to put the setState in the async callbacks.

Am I doing this right or wrong?  Will it cause a problem to be executing setState from within async callbacks?

Comment: There's actually a great example in the React docs that describes just this scenario with a code example, where they do put `setState` within the callback (https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is perfectly fine. The only thing you'll want to watch out for is the fact that your Ajax request could finish *after* the component is unmounted for some reason; thus, you'll want to make sure everything gets cleaned up if your component is unmounted. See [isMounted is an Antipattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can set async componentDidMount like this :

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const res = await fetch('https://example.com')
  const something = await res.json()
  this.setState({something})
}
```